# SDL_ttf not working in codeblocks

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, truetype, sdl-ttf

how do you set up sdl_ttf in codeblocks? Ive read lazyfoo's tutorial about adding new libraries to sdl, and have successfully added sdl_image to it. however, ttf refuses to work. i have downloaded the files, put the header file in the sdl folder, put the dlls and lib in syswow64 and added a -lSDL_ttf to the linker settings, but i keep on getting the error `ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL_ttf|` how do i fix this?

Comment: check if you have .so in the correct path (`/usr/lib`?). Make an `locate sdl_image` and look where is it.

Comment: wow. i found what i did wrong

Answer (score 1):

try -lSDL2_ttf because SDL_ttf library changed its name in SDL2

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-dev`

Or in Windows, make sure you put the SDL_ttf libs and includes into the SDL folders.